# PyQt Hide Contents of QTabWidget but keep QTabBar visible

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtabwidget

I was wondering if it is possible in PyQt, when trying to hide QTabWidget, to hide the contents themselves, but keep the QTabBar visible.

As of now, I have custom TabBar and TabWidget that inherit from QTabBar and QTabWidget. My TabBar is vertical and on the west side of the TabWidget.

I have created the button and connected a slot to it that is supposed to hide the TabWidget. Issue is, hiding the TabWidget hides the TabBar, which I do not want.

I have tried overriding .hide() method, tried

```
self.tab_widget.hide()
self.tab_widget.tabBar().show()
```

But nothing works, since the TabWidget is the parent of TabBar, hiding TabWidget, automatically hides TabBar.

Of course I could probably construct my own poor man's TabWidget from two widgets so that I could hide and show the widgets whenever I want, but inhereting from QTabWidget is very convenient and I do not want to do it from scratch.

I also upon hiding could just resize tab widget to the width of the TabBar, but I feel that is stupid solution as well.

My Idea is to have an expandable/shrinkable and hideable sidebar, such as in VSCode.
[image]

Solutions in C++ QT will be helpful as well, as I understand both, and it is not necessarily Python issue, but Qt.

Comment: A `QTabWisget` is essentially just a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) and a [QTabBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html) inside a `QWidget` container so it's quite trivial to implement a custom version yourself. Alternatively, you could try manipulating the internal stack-widget of the `QTabWisget` (e.g. via `tabWidget.findChild(QStackedWidget)`). However, it's unclear what exactly you mean by "*hide the contents*". Are you expecting the entire widget to resize in some way as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTabWidget is a composite widget, made of a QTabBar and a QStackedWidget.

Most importantly, it overrides basic aspects that are required for layout management, such as [`sizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop), [`minimumSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop) and [`sizePolicy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop).

You cannot just toggle the visibility of the tab bar (nor the stacked widget contents):

1. as you already found out, hiding the QTabWidget and showing the tab bar is fundamentally a no-op, since the parent visibility has precedence: calling `show()` or `setVisible(True)` on a *nested* child (a QWidget without a `Qt.Window` window flag) will only make it visible as long as the parent is shown;
2. trying to hide the stacked widget is irrelevant, because the QTabWidget size hint functions will always consider the stacked widget hints, no matter the visibility;

This is a possible implementation that toggles visibility of the tab "pages" whenever a tab is clicked on the currently visible page (if any): clicking on a currently selected and visible tab will always hide the contents, while contents will be made visible when clicking on any tab, even if no contents are visible.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ToggleTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    _contentsVisible = True
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.tabBarClicked.connect(self.toggleContentsVisibleFromClick)
        self._stackedWidget = self.findChild(QStackedWidget)

    def toggleContentsVisibleFromClick(self, index):
        if not self._contentsVisible or index == self.currentIndex():
            self.toggleContentsVisibility()

    def toggleContentsVisibility(self):
        self.setContentsVisible(not self._contentsVisible)

    def setContentsVisible(self, visible):
        if self._contentsVisible != visible:
            self._contentsVisible = visible
            self._stackedWidget.setVisible(visible)
            self.setDocumentMode(not visible)

            tabHint = self.tabBar().sizeHint()
            maxSize = 16777215 # default maximum size
            if not self.tabPosition() & self.West:
                # horizontal
                if not visible:
                    maxSize = tabHint.height()
                self.setMaximumHeight(maxSize)
            else:
                if not visible:
                    maxSize = tabHint.width()
                self.setMaximumWidth(maxSize)


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tabWidget = ToggleTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(QTextEdit('hello world'), 'Hello')
        self.tabWidget.addTab(QTextEdit('bye world'), 'Bye')
        self.table = QTableWidget(10, 2)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)


app = QApplication([])
test = Test()
test.show()
app.exec()
```

Note that:

- this doesn't consider style changes (including further calls to `setStyleSheet()`) or font changes that might affect the size of the tab bar;
- a proper implementation should not use `setMaximum<size-or-dimension>()`, but override `sizeHint()` and `minimumSizeHint()` instead, and it should also consider possible changes in the tab widget size policy;
- due to the above, explicit changes in the `maximum<size-or-dimension>` done outside of the class should be taken into account;
- the `setDocumentMode` is used to completely "hide" the contents of the tab pages, and will ignore any previous or further explicit call; if you need to use that property, you have to implement a further property that manages the explicitly set value and the internal one set by the visibility toggling;